# Like/Dislike function using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on creating a like/dislike functionality for my site using AJAX and PHP. Here's my js code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.ups .fa').live('click', function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        url : loggmax_ratings.ajaxurl,
        data : { 
            action: "loggmax_ratings_like_post", 
            dislike_num : $this.closest('.pointer').find('.downs').attr('data-dislike_num'),
            like_num : $this.parent().attr('data-like_num'), 
            user_id : loggmax_ratings.user_id, 
            post_id : loggmax_ratings.post_id, 
            ip : loggmax_ratings.ip
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $this.parent().attr('data-like_num', response['like_num']);
            $this.parent().find('em').text(response['like_num']);
            if(response['dislike_num'] != $this.closest('.pointer').find('.downs').attr('data-dislike_num')) {
                if($this.closest('.pointer').find('.downs').find('.pull-left').hasClass('active')) {
                    $this.closest('.pointer').find('.downs').find('.pull-left').removeClass('active');
                }else{
                    $this.closest('.pointer').find('.downs').find('.pull-left').addClass('active');
                }
            }
            $this.closest('.pointer').find('.downs').attr('data-dislike_num', response['dislike_num']);
            $this.closest('.pointer').find('.downs').find('em').text(response['dislike_num']);
            if($this.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.removeClass('active');
            }else{
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
});

$('.downs .fa').live('click', function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        url : loggmax_ratings.ajaxurl,
        data : { 
            action: "loggmax_ratings_dislike_post", 
            like_num : $this.closest('.pointer').find('.ups').attr('data-like_num'),
            dislike_num : $this.parent().attr('data-dislike_num'), 
            user_id : loggmax_ratings.user_id, 
            post_id : loggmax_ratings.post_id, 
            ip : loggmax_ratings.ip
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $this.parent().attr('data-dislike_num', response['dislike_num']);
            $this.parent().find('em').text(response['dislike_num']);
            if(response['like_num'] != $this.closest('.pointer').find('.ups').attr('data-like_num')) {
                if($this.closest('.pointer').find('.ups').find('.pull-left').hasClass('active')) {
                    $this.closest('.pointer').find('.ups').find('.pull-left').removeClass('active');
                }else{
                    $this.closest('.pointer').find('.ups').find('.pull-left').addClass('active');
                }
            }
            $this.closest('.pointer').find('.ups').attr('data-like_num', response['like_num']);
            $this.closest('.pointer').find('.ups').find('em').text(response['like_num']);
            if($this.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.removeClass('active');
            }else{
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

And here's my markup:

```
<div class='rating-buttons-block artticle-rating-buttons-block pull-left' itemprop='aggregateRating' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/AggregateRating'>
   <span class='pointer rating-button ups pull-left' data-like_num='0'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i><em class='upsNumber'>0</em></span>
   <span class='pointer rating-button downs pull-left' data-like_num='0'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i><em class='downsNumber'>0</em></span>
</div>
```

So far, when I click on the Like icon, the number becomes -1, and when I click again, it becomes -2, and so on. The dislike icon doesn't work at all.
What I want to achieve is to increase the likes and dislikes when it is clicked, and also to add the class `active` in the `span` attribute when the any of the icons has been clicked.

I'm totally new to Javascript/jQuery. Any ideas on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: How does the server side work? Is that tested and working?

Comment: I just changed the `.live()` to `.on()` now, but still the same result. Like button returns a negative result upon clicking.

Comment: @Lucero, please what exactly do you mean by server side?

Comment: Cos I was actually 'thinking' that, at least, on clicking on any of the icons, the class should change to active, then if it doesn't bring out the required number, then I'll have to look at the PHP code that I wrote for the action.

Comment: The PHP code runs on the server, the JavaScript runs on the client (browser). To me the AJAX call data sent to the server doesn't make much sense which is why I'm asking if that works...

Comment: Okay, do you suggest I include the PHP code to the question?

Comment: Or, how do I rewrite it to make it work?

Comment: You could start by answering the question I initially asked: have you tested the server code, e.g. with a AJAX test tool/extension or similar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126472/discussion-between-samuel-asor-and-lucero).